# Trying to use same foreGroundNotification for 2 different services

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-mediaplayer, intentservice

OK, so I am trying to use the same notification for 2 different fore-ground Services.

1. I have a music player service, which plays music....duh.
2. I have a downloader service which downloads the music file.

I have tried the following so far :

1. I kept the music Player service non-foreground :
   I observed that when the download service finished and its foreground status got finished, my static final mediaPlayer which was in the other service got GC'ed. Basically my whole music player service stopped. This is probably the expected behavior and this happens quite randomly, not right after downloader finishes.
2. I called startForeground() in both services : 
   In this case as as soon as either of the 2 services finished, the foreground notification vanished. Probably foreground status in both services was not achieved. In any-case, my music-player can still get GC'ed.

What I plan on doing :

1. Somehow, have the knowledge that the notification is showing and we should not call start-foreground rather just update it (if any of the 2 services is in foreground, the associated process can not get GC'ed, so in my opinion my music player is safe, even if the actual service is not in foreground, am I correct in assuming this ?)
2. Merge the 2 services (really wanna avoid this)

Would appreciate some advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a single service that runs in the foreground (when it needs to) and have that service hold instances of your player and down loader. They don't need to be services, they can just be plain objects  This might be a variation of your option 2, but it seems like the right approach to me at least.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late.
Can you elaborate on "They don't need to be services, they can just be plain objects"

Comment: It seems like you have 2 background operations that you want to keep going using 1 service that runs in the foreground and displays a notification.  I don't know exactly how these run, but lets say they each used AsyncTask as an example.  You could encapsulate each background task in an AsyncTask based object, and then instantiate each of those objects in your 1 service.